# Reshape array in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, array

I am using a PostgreSQL 10 server, in which I have some tables containing attributes of type `double precision[]` intended for storing 1D arrays of data, of length ~1000. My code interacting with the database contained a bug that inserted data as an array of length-1 arrays (see [my psycopg bug report](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/676) where I eventually worked out that this is what was happening), but this was [permitted by the DBMS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html):

> The current implementation does not enforce the declared number of
>   dimensions either. Arrays of a particular element type are all
>   considered to be of the same type, regardless of size or number of
>   dimensions. So, declaring the array size or number of dimensions in
>   `CREATE TABLE` is simply documentation; it does not affect run-time
>   behavior.

How can I fix these misshapen arrays within the DBMS (i.e., using SQL rather than updating from external code)? I essentially wish to just flatten each array into a 1D array as originally intended.

A snippet of the array data as returned by `psql` is:

```
{{2.20751909662576},{2.20679071024511},{2.20615506273571},{2.2055910715332},{2.
20507756148068},{2.20459435596551},{2.20412336646322},{2.20364958013081},{2.2031
618420891},{2.20265334228114},{2.20212174686242},{2.20156895755458},{2.201000532
12516},{2.20042484573123},{2.19985210697606},{2.19929335742568},{2.1987595765431
},{2.19826098783408},{2.19780662274576},{2.19740415504621},{2.19705997866427},{2
.19677947299938},{2.1965673849541},{2.19642825612809},{2.1963668334181},{2.19638 ...
```

Comment: Show us the code that inserted the data and how the data currently looks like e.g. the output of a `select` statement of that table as [**formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name example of data now added. I don't think the inserting code will help as it's using opaque `numpy` arrays and `pandas` dataframes that I'm in the process of debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
update the_table 
  set data = x.data
from (
  select t.id, array_agg(d.x order by d.idx) as data
  from the_table t, unnest(data) with ordinality as d(x, idx)
  group by t.id
) x
where x.id = the_table.id;
```

Sample psql output:

```
postgres=> create table the_table (id integer primary key, data double precision[]);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=> insert into the_table values
postgres->   (1, '{{2.20751909662576},{2.20679071024511},{2.20615506273571},{2.2055910715332},{2.20507756148068},{2.20459435596551},{2.20412336646322},{2.20364958013081}}'),
postgres->   (2, '{{2.19780662274576},{2.19740415504621},{2.19705997866427},{2.19677947299938},{2.1965673849541},{2.19642825612809},{2.1963668334181}}');
INSERT 0 2
postgres=> select *
postgres-> from the_table;
 id |                                                                           data
----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | {{2.20751909662576},{2.20679071024511},{2.20615506273571},{2.2055910715332},{2.20507756148068},{2.20459435596551},{2.20412336646322},{2.20364958013081}}
  2 | {{2.19780662274576},{2.19740415504621},{2.19705997866427},{2.19677947299938},{2.1965673849541},{2.19642825612809},{2.1963668334181}}
(2 rows)

postgres=> update the_table
postgres->   set data = x.data
postgres-> from (
postgres(>   select t.id, array_agg(d.x order by d.idx) as data
postgres(>   from the_table t, unnest(data) with ordinality as d(x, idx)
postgres(>   group by t.id
postgres(> ) x
postgres-> where x.id = the_table.id;
UPDATE 2
postgres=> select *
postgres-> from the_table;
 id |                                                                   data
----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | {2.20751909662576,2.20679071024511,2.20615506273571,2.2055910715332,2.20507756148068,2.20459435596551,2.20412336646322,2.20364958013081}
  2 | {2.19780662274576,2.19740415504621,2.19705997866427,2.19677947299938,2.1965673849541,2.19642825612809,2.1963668334181}
(2 rows)

postgres=>
```

Comment: Much nicer than my hacky serialization/deserialization via strings approach, thanks. I'll test it now.

Comment: Works beautifully. Out of interest, is the use of `WITH ORDINALITY` essential? Are no guarantees made about the order of unnested array data without it?

Comment: An order is never guaranteed without an `order by` and the only way to do an `array_agg()` with an order by is if the original array index is available.